# CSS hover div change another div style (not under same parent)

Tags: html, css, hover

See Example 3 in fiddle below...

https://jsfiddle.net/8opnvq37/1/

HTML

```
Example 1
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<br /><br />
Example 2
<div class="a">A</div>
<div id="box"><div class="b">B</div></div>
<br /><br />
Example 3
<div id="box2"><div class="a">A</div></div>
<div class="b">B</div>
```

CSS

```
.a:hover ~ .b,
.a:hover ~ #box .b
{
background: #3F6;
}
```

As you can see Example 1 & 2 are working when you hover over A. I know for the hover effect to work, the elements has to be under the same parent— unless you specify it— in Example 2. But how do you get it to work when .a is under a different parent as shown in Example 3??

Comment: It is unclear for me what your are saying?

Comment: Sorry I am trying to make "B" background turn green when you hover over "A" in Example 3. And "A" has to be inside another div (#box2)

Answer (score 0):

Does it absolutely need to be hovering on the .a element? I'm not sure it's possible with pure css if so. This would work, though:

```
#box2:hover ~ .b { background: #3f6; }
```

Comment: Yeah, I get that. That's not quite what I was asking. See fiddle of my answer: https://jsfiddle.net/tcquhcby/

Comment: But there are multiple (different) elements within #box2 that I need to target

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got that to work using javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/6vh5L2t0/

HTML

```
<div id="c">Div C</div>
---
<div id="box">
<div id="d">Div D</div></div>
```

Javascipt

```
$('#d').hover(
function(){
$('#c').css('background', '#F00')
}, 
function() { 
$('#c').css('background', '')
});
```